# How to load/integrate my external Js file into Maui Blazor?

Tags: .net, blazor, maui

In Blazor-Server I put the call for external js-files in the **_Layout.cshtml** file and use/call it like this:

```
<script src="js/my.js"></script>
```

I put the file my.js in wwwroot/js/. I want to do the same thing in .Net Maui-Blazor App.

In which file do I put the <script ...> call in Maui?

Comment: According to the Microsoft document you can follow this article and here is the website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: the keyword maui can not be found in the link. Are you sure that the article talks about maui and not only Blazor!

Comment: Sorry, I might misunderstand your meaning. If you want to use JS file in Maui, put the code `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` in the html file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guess I have found the answere it is:

wwwroot/**index.html**

(in this file add e.g. `<script src="js/my.js"></script>` after the `</html>`)